# Integral Basis for Cubic Fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm trying to follow a text (Lang's *Algebraic Number Theory*) in which it fully determines an integral basis for quadratic fields (also seen [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136631/mathbbq-sqrtd-with-specific-integral-basis)). Is there any easy or analogous way to determine one for cubic fields of the form $\mathbb Q(\sqrt[3]{a})$, where $a\in\mathbb Z$?

Can one also conclude (or stipulate various restrictions so) that $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID?

Comment: http://www.math.ku.dk/~kiming/lecture_notes/2003-2004-algebraic_number_theory_koch/pure_cubic_fields.pdf

Comment: $\mathcal{O}_K$ is not in general a PID when $K$ is quadratic, so there should be less hope for when $K$ is cubic.

Comment: If you know about the ideal class group, then $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a PID if and only if its class number (i.e. the order of the ideal class group) is 1. This wikipedia article has a list of some quadratic and cubic fields with class number 1: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_number_fields_with_class_number_one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find an "elementary" proof in example 4.3.6 of Murty and Esmonde, Problems in Algebraic Number Theory, [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=YaqVpdrngNYC&lpg=PA47&dq=murty%20esmonde%204.3.6&hl=de&pg=PA48#v=onepage&q=murty%20esmonde%204.3.6&f=false%5d).

Answer (score 6):

Integral basis for ${\bf Q}(\root3\of a)$ is given in Theorem 7.3.2 of Alaca and Williams, Introductory Algebraic Number Theory:

Let $m$ be a cubefree integer. Set $m=hk^2$, where $h$ is squarefree, so that $k$ is squarefree and $(h,k)=1$. Set $\theta=m^{1/3}$ and $K={\bf Q}(\theta)$. Then an integral basis for $K$ is $$\eqalign{&\{{1,\theta,\theta^2/k\}},{\rm\ if\ }m^2\not\equiv1\pmod9,\cr&\{{1,\theta,(k^2\pm k^2\theta+\theta^2)/3k\}},{\rm\ if\ }m\equiv\pm1\pmod9.\cr}$$

Comment: I do not have access to the text, but as far as I can [gleam online](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99913/easy-way-to-show-that-mathbbz-sqrt32-is-the-ring-of-integers-of-mat), the proof to that theorem is left to the reader (!).

Comment: Yes, that's right. Considering how complex the statement is, you might want to reconsider asking for an easy way to determine an integral basis for these fields.

Comment: The ring of integers of a pure cubic field is entirely known, see e.g.https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3508522/300700