# Show that $x$, $y$, $z$ are integers when $3x$, $3x^2-6yz$, $x^3+2y^3+4z^3-6xyz$ are integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I was trying to show that $\{1, \alpha, \alpha^2\}$ is a integral basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ where $\alpha= \sqrt[3]{2}$.

And after some steps it remains to prove that if $$3x, \quad 3x^2-6yz, \quad x^3+2y^3+4z^3-6xyz \quad $$ are integers and $x$, $y$, $z$ $\in \mathbb{Q}$ then $x$, $y$, $z$ are integers.  And I know that the denominators of $x$, $y$, $z$ are divisors of $6$. I managed to prove some facts but nothing that really helps to conclude.

Any easy ways to solve this one?

Comment: I think you intend to assume that $x, y, z \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yeah exactly, my mistake. But it is kinda obvious if you think of the original task.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/99913/11619) or [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/250428/11619) for more discussion. And this is in Murty & Esmonde, which you can borrow from a teacher near you.

Answer (score 0):

Your assertion seems untrue.

Let $x=1$, $yz=1$.

Let $t+\frac{2}{t}=4$ and $y^3=t, z^3=\frac{1}{t}$.

A counter-example.

Comment: I think when OP said "the denominators of $x,y,z$ are divisors of $6$, it implied that $x, y,$ and $z$ are supposed to be rational, which your value of $t$ is not. (But I really like your example!)

Comment: Yeah, the numbers should be rational.