# A special type of prime decompositions in a subfield of a cyclotomic field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $l$ be an odd prime number and $\zeta$ be a primitive $l$-th  root of unity in $\mathbb{C}$.
Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$.
Let $A$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
Let $G$ be the Galois group of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta)/\mathbb{Q}$.
$G$ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}/l\mathbb{Z})^*$.
Hence $G$ is a cyclic group of order $l - 1$.
Let $f$ be a positive divisor of $l - 1$.
There exists a unique subgroup $G_f$ of $G$ whose order is $f$.
Let $K_f$ be the fixed subfield of $K$ by $G_f$.
Let $A_f$ be the ring of algebraic integers of $K_f$.
Let $p$ be a prime number whose order mod $l$ is $f$.
There exists a prime ideal $P$ of $A_f$ lying over $p$.

My question: Is the following proposition true? If yes, how would you prove this?

**Proposition**
The degree of $P$ is 1.

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/174425/periods-of-a-cyclotomic-field) is a related topic.

Answer (score 2):

The decomposition group at $p$ in $G$ is the unique subgroup of order $f$.  Thus it equals $G_f$.  Consequently the decomposition group at $p$ in $G/G_f$ is trivial, and so $p$ splits completely in $K_f$.  This proves the proposition.