# When are the roots of polynomials with rational coefficients rationally independent?

Tags: galois-theory, radicals, irreducible-polynomials, irrational-numbers

Im wondering, for a polynomial $P(x)=x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0$, $a_i \in \mathbb Q$ with roots $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n \in \mathbb C$.
Under what conditions are $\alpha_i$ rationally independent?, i.e. $\forall \lambda_i\in \mathbb Q$
$$\sum_i \lambda_i\alpha_i=0 \rightarrow \lambda_1=\lambda_2=\dots=\lambda_n=0$$

It seems clear that since $\sum_i \alpha_i=-a_{n-1}$, one needs that $a_{n-1}\neq 0$, all $\alpha_i\not\in \mathbb Q$ and also P(x) needs to be irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ since for $P(x)=Q(x)R(x)$  one has $$\frac{1}{ a^Q_{n_Q-1}}\sum_i \alpha_i^{Q}-\frac{1}{ a^R_{n_R-1}}\sum_i \alpha_i^{R}=0$$ with $\alpha^Q,a^Q$ the roots and coefficients of Q.

Are there any other conditions that have to be met? The Galois group being $S_n$ appears to be enough but also too strong of a requirement. I appreciate any help.

Also in case of rational dependence, is it possible to find a rationally independent basis for the roots efficiently?

Edit: I would really also appreciate a counter example, i.e. an irreducible polynomial $P(x)$ of degree $n>1$ (implies $\alpha_i\not\in\mathbb Q$), where $a_{n-1}\neq 0$, but rational dependence between the roots of $P(x)$.

Comment: Well, you need $a_{n-1}\neq 0$ else $\sum \alpha_i=0$.

Comment: When $n=2$, it is easy to see that the two roots are independent over $\mathbb Q$ iff $a_1^2-4a_0$ is not a square and $a_1\neq 0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a complete answer. $P(x)$ irreducible and $a_{n-1} \neq 0$ are necessary, as you say. I don't understand your notation regarding the reducible case, but if $P(x) = Q(x) R(x)$ then the roots of $Q(x)$ sum up to something rational and so do the roots of $R(x)$, so some rational linear combination of these two sums is zero.

Next, if $P(x)$ is irreducible and $a_{n-1} \neq 0$, write $I$ for the set of roots of $P(x)$, where the root corresponding to $i \in I$ is denoted $\alpha_i$, and write $G$ for its Galois group. Consider the space $V$ of vectors $(\lambda_i) \in \mathbb{Q}^I$ such that $\sum \lambda_i \alpha_i = 0$; since applying an element of the Galois group to such a linear dependence produces another linear dependence, $V$ is a $G$-submodule of $\mathbb{Q}^I$. Averaging over $G$, we get that if $\sum \lambda_i \alpha_i = 0$ then

$$\frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} g \sum \lambda_i \alpha_i = \sum \lambda_i \frac{\sum \alpha_i}{n} = 0$$

so if $a_{n-1} \neq 0$ then $\sum \lambda_i = 0$; so our $G$-module $V$ of linear dependencies lives in the submodule of $\mathbb{Q}^I$ of vectors summing to zero. Call this submodule $W$.

> **Proposition:** $W$ is irreducible iff $G$ acts doubly transitively on the roots.

*Proof.* Write $\chi$ for the character of $W$. Then $\chi + 1$ is the character of $\mathbb{Q}^I$, which is $\text{Fix}(g)$, the number of fixed points of $g \in G$ acting on the roots. Hence

$$\langle \chi + 1, \chi + 1 \rangle = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \text{Fix}(g)^2$$

and by Burnside's lemma this is the number of orbits of $G$ acting on $I \times I$. On the other hand, $\langle \chi + 1, \chi + 1 \rangle = \langle \chi, \chi \rangle + 1$ ($\langle \chi, 1 \rangle = 0$ because the action of $G$ on the roots is always transitive, which gives $\langle \chi + 1, 1 \rangle = 1$, again by Burnside's lemma). So $\chi$ is irreducible iff $\langle \chi, \chi \rangle = 1$ iff $G$ has exactly two orbits on $I \times i$, which is exactly the condition that $G$ acts doubly transitively (since the diagonal $(i, i)$ is always an orbit). $\Box$

> **Corollary:** With the above hypotheses, if $G$ acts doubly transitively on the roots then the roots are linearly independent.

This implies in particular that the roots are linearly independent if $G = S_n$ but various other Galois groups are possible, such as the affine linear groups $AGL_1(\mathbb{F}_p) \cong \mathbb{F}_p \rtimes \mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$ acting on $\mathbb{F}_p$.

*Proof.* If $G$ acts doubly transitively on the roots then it acts irreducibly on $W$, as above. It follows that if $\sum \lambda_i \alpha_i = 0$ is a nontrivial linear dependence among the roots then $V$ is nonzero, hence (by irreducibility) must be all of $W$. But $W$ contains all permutations of vectors of the form $(1, -1, \dots 0)$, which gives that $\alpha_i - \alpha_j = 0$ for all $i \neq j$; contradiction. So $V = 0$, meaning there are no nontrivial linear dependencies among the roots. $\Box$

This condition is not necessary, since for example the roots of $P(x) = \frac{x^p - 1}{x - 1} = \Phi_p(x)$, for $p$ a prime, are also linearly independent but the Galois group, which is $\mathbb{F}_p^{\times}$, does not act double transitively. Apparently [it's known](https://mathoverflow.net/a/126978/290) that the primitive $n^{th}$ roots of unity (so the roots of $\Phi_n(x)$) are linearly independent iff $n$ is squarefree but I don't know a proof or reference.

**Edit:** Ah, I've missed an obvious generalization that covers the case of $\Phi_p(x)$. Double transitivity actually shows that $W \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathbb{C}$ is irreducible, whereas for the above argument to go through it suffices that $W$ itself is irreducible, over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is true in the case of $\Phi_p(x)$. I don't know how to check irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ in general, though. I guess it is necessary and sufficient that the irreducible components of $W$ over $\mathbb{C}$ form a single Galois orbit.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess main problem with using Galois groups here is that it considers symmetries in all algebraic equations, not just linear ones. In the case of roots of unity they are multiplicative ($\omega_i\omega_j=\omega_{i+j}$), so they do not really apply.

Comment: Good stuff as always :-). I happened to recall [another thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/87290/11619), where the case of cyclotomic polynomials is looked at, so I felt like adding a link. Particularly as the question contains a reference.